# React Component List Returning D3 SVG With Images All The Same As First Image In The List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

So I've made a React component that will return a D3 SVG element that takes in an image and then displays it with some text wrapped around the image. However, when I use the component with multiple images, it seems that it sets all the images to be the first in the list. [Example (the actual picture needed to be displayed is on bottom, while the SVG only shows the first).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blhme.jpg)

What might be going on here? Would it happen to be something to do with how I'm selecting? My render function is as follows:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div ref="arc" style={{ minHeight: 225}}></div>
    )
  }
```

And my d3.select is as follows:

```
    context = d3.select(this.refs.arc).append('svg')
          .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMaxYMin slice")
          .attr('viewBox', '0 0 '+width+' '+height)
          .classed("svg-content", true)
        .append('g').attr('class', 'wrapper')
          .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`)


    setImage(context, id){
        var width, height;
        width = height = this.props.innerRadius*2;

        return context
          // .selectAll('.images')
          // .data(this.props.img).enter()
          .append('defs')
            .attr('class', 'images')
          .append('pattern')
            .attr('id', id)
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("x", -width/2)
            .attr("y", -height/2)
          .append('image')
            // .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {return d})
            .attr('xlink:href', this.props.img)
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
        ;

      }

      drawImage(context, size, id){
        const { height, width } = this.props;
        return context
          .append('circle')
          .attr('r', size)
          .attr('id', id)
          .style('fill', 'url(#'+id+')')    
        ;
      }
```

Can anyone tell me what might be going on? I'll post any relevant information upon request.

**Update:** [I decided to try passing text in as well, and THAT seems to update. Not sure whats going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mymLP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was an idiot and hadn't set an unique ID for each of the images, and they were all being set as the same ID. Thus the `.style('fill', 'url(#'+id+')')` was always only filling using the ID of the very first image.